# Node.js using sendgrid to send template

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid

I have created a very simple "Hello world" template in `sendgrid`.

Now i wish to send an email using this template from my `node server`

normally to send a mail i have to do something like this:

```
    email.send = function (Object) {
    sendgrid.send({
        from: Object.from,
        to: Object.to,
        subject: Object.subject,
        html: Object.html,
        text: Object.text
    }, function (err, json) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('SendGrid error:');
            return console.error(err);
        }
        console.log('SendGrid success');
    });
};
```

However im not sure how i can include my template?

I can't seem to find documentation on the subject so i hope you guys are able to help me.

Comment: Not clear on what you mean by "send an email using this template".

Comment: @Paul in sengrid you can create templates i wish to send a mail using that template

Comment: You might be looking for this https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs#templates

Comment: @Sami Yep your correct i found it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used 'email-templates-v2' for my project. First compile your template file like this:

```
var EmailTemplate = require('email-templates-v2').EmailTemplate;
var templateDir = constants.email_templates_path + 'user-line-won';
var userWonTemplate = new EmailTemplate( templateDir );
```

Now, for passing context data to your template, create a context object. For example:

```
var templateContext = {};
templateContext.user = req.session.user;
templateContext.campaign = req.campaign;
templateContext.project = req.project;
```

Now, render the template and send the mail in the callback function. You get the compiled template in the success callback:

```
userWonTemplate.render(templateContext, function (err, results) {
if( err )
                {
                    console.log( err );
                    res.render('error', {'title': 'Error', 'error': err, 'session': req.session});
                }
                else
                {
                    var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
                    var mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport();
                    var mailOptions = {
                        from: fromEmail,
                        to: toEmail,
                        subject: subjectEmail,
                        text: "A user subject line has won.\n",
                        html: results.html
                    };
                    mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
                        if(error){
                            console.log(error);
                        }else{
                            console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
                        }
                    });
                    next();
                }
            });
```

I have used nodemailer, but passing the compiled html to sendgrid should work similarly.

Comment: This is exactly what i want to avoid (if i can) using this will require alot of code where i hoped i could just use sendgrid's api to use the template i made there to keep my code neat and tiny

Comment: yes, @Sami pointed this out clearly in his comment. My answer is irrelevant in this context. :(